# How to do video streaming using database value in struts2

Tags: eclipse, jsp, video, struts2

Hi guys am trying play video in jsp with database value its fetch video from system local drives but if i pasted video under web content eclipse video will play how can i resolve this error?

**code used having video file under web content in eclipse**

```
<video width="400" controls>
 <source src="Sample.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
  <source src="mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

**Trying to fetch and play from system local drive**

**jsp**

```
<html>
<body>

 <%
  String url = request.getScheme() + "://" + request.getServerName()
    + ":" + request.getServerPort() + request.getContextPath();
  url = url + "//download";
 %>
 <video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src=<%=url%>>
 </video>
</body>
</html>
```

**action class**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class DownloadAction extends ActionSupport {

    private InputStream fileInputStream;
    private String fileToDownload = "/video/Sample.mp4";
    private String fileName;

    private String contentType = "video/mp4";

    public String getContentType() {
        return contentType;
    }

    public void setContentType(String contentType) {
        this.contentType = contentType;
    }

    public void setFileName(String fileName) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }

    public InputStream getFileInputStream() {
        fileName = "notes.docx";
        return fileInputStream;
    }

    public String execute() throws Exception {
        fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(fileToDownload));
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public String getFileName() {
        return fileName;
    }

}
```

**struts xml**

```
<struts>
 <package name="default" extends="struts-default">
  <action name="download" class="com.sample.actions.DownloadAction">
   <result name="success" type="stream">
    <param name="contentType">${contentType}</param>
    <param name="inputName">fileInputStream</param>
    <param name="contentDisposition">attachment;filename="${fileName}"</param>
    <param name="bufferSize">1024</param>
   </result>
  </action>
 </package>
</struts>
```